# Error using pytesseract

Tags: python-2.7, pytesser

I am using pytesseract to convert images to text. I successfully installed pytesseract with pip command. But when i run the script, it shows me error : `No module named Tesseract`.

These are my codes :

```
from tesseract import image_to_string
image = Image.open('input-NEAREST.tif')
print image_to_string(image)
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\J's MAgic\Desktop\py\new1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tesseract import image_to_string
ImportError: No module named tesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tess

print tess.image_to_string(Image.open('3.png'), lang='tur')
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

It should be not `from tesseract import image_to_string`, but `from pytesseract import image_to_string`.
Also, there are some problems with pip installation of pytesseract and lack of documentation of how properly install pytesseract, and I believe you will receive error when you will run your code. If you will be able to run your program that's great, but if you will receive error, do following: Download "tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe" file from [Sourceforge tesseract-ocr page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/?source=navbar)
and install it simply running .exe file in some specific folder. After, add this folder to your PATH environment. Then try to run your program.